# How to one date per row for all dates between 2 dates?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I know this question seem complicated but what I want to do is simple, I got 2 columns:

- I is my Starting Date
- L is my ending date
- G is where all the dates are supposed to be

What I want to do is get the number of days per period (EndDate - StartDate + 1), add this many rows and change value of G to be written day per day.

I already coded the part below, but it doesn't seem to be right:

```
Sub Dates()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim addrows
Dim FindDates
Dim CountDays
Dim dddays
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim ir As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
End With
addrows = 2

For ir = 1 To LastRow
    FindDates = ws.Range("I" & addrows).Value
    CountDays = ws.Range("L" & addrows).Value - ws.Range("I" & addrows).Value + 1
    Adddays = 0

    For i = 1 To CountDays
        ws2.Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        ws2.Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & addrows).Value
        ws2.Range("C2").Value = FindDates + Adddays
        ws2.Range("C2").Value = ws.Range("G" & addrows).Value
        Adddays = Adddays + 1
    Next i
        addrows = addrows + 1

Next ir

End Sub
```

File looks as follows:
[image]

Can you help me a bit? "ws2.Range("C2").Value = FindDates + Adddays" is giving me an error 13

Comment: Please, could you post an example of how your data looks like?

Comment: Is `FindDates` a number? You should probably declare the type up to `Dim FindDates as Long` or such.

Comment: Have you consider using [DataSeries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-dataseries-method-excel)?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I updated the original question with a screenshot, do you mind having a look at it? 
And Never heard of DataSeries, it's the first time I use VBA, how do you use it?

Comment: Not sure if this will work for you, but try it manually first. I understand you have an array of Start Dates and End Dates. And for each Start Date, you want to insert a new row with a date, until End Date is reached. And so on will all dates in your array. Something **[LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnpCq.jpg)** . And about DataSeries, try it manually if you want. **[Read this tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-list-of-sequential-dates-aa1c0fa7-c76a-4762-8bc9-46f1691defec)**

Comment: Thanks man! I'm gonna try this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - I is my Starting Date
> - L is my ending date
> - G is where all the dates are supposed to be
>
> What I want to do is get the number of days per period (EndDate - StartDate + 1), add this many rows and change value of G to be written day per day.

for what above this should help you:

```
Sub Dates()
    Dim ir As Long, countDays As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For ir = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1
            With .Rows(ir)
                countDays = .range("L1") - .range("I1") + 1
                If countDays > 1 Then
                    .Offset(1).Resize(countDays - 1).Insert xlDown
                    .Offset(1).Resize(countDays - 1).value = .value
                    With .Resize(countDays).Columns("G")
                        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC9+ROW()-" & .Rows(1).row
                        .value = .value
                    End With
                End If                        
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't really get what this line does .Offset(1).Resize(countDays - 1).value = .value

Comment: it copies the current row content across all newly inserted rows. If this answer solves your question you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you